# Is it possible to specify a custom Kotlin compiler in build.gradle?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I would like to experiment with a custom (i.e. unreleased) Kotlin compiler version in a gradle project (I have a specific branch on the Kotlin compiler's git that I'd like to try out). However, I have not been able to find any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Gradle plugins for unreleased versions doesn't exist yet, the only way to use a compiler is through a CLI. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/command-line.html

You can try to automate things using Gradle tasks, yet you'll probably have to write everything yourself.